# Pandas not in index error trying a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, scatter

I was trying to do a scatter plot. I was trying with the next code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [10,20]})
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
df
df.plot.scatter(df['a'], df['b'])
```

I get the error

> KeyError: '[1 2] not in index'

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

This line is redundant:

```
df.plot.scatter(df['a'], df['b'])
```

Since you've already called `df`, you only need to refer to the column heading, like so:

```
df.plot.scatter('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 1):

First no problem you are new in python ;)

Need parameter `x` and `y` in [`DataFrame.plot.scatter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [10,20]})
df.columns = ['a', 'b']

df.plot.scatter(x = 'a', y='b')
```

[image: graph]